# num_rows() and result_array() in the same function ? codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a question.
I have a function in a model to select products:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $this->db->select(dbColumnProductsId . ',' . dbColumnProductsName . ',' . dbColumnProductsImage . ',' . dbColumnProductsPrice . ',' . dbColumnProductsStock . ',' . dbColumnCategoryId . ',' . dbColumnCategoryName);
    $this->db->join(dbTableCategory, dbTableCategory . '.' . dbColumnCategoryId . '=' . dbTableProducts . '.' . dbColumnProductsCategory);
    $this->db->order_by(dbColumnProductsId, 'DESC');
    $this->db->from(dbTableProducts);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

But now I need to make a pagination of these products. How did I can use the "num_rows" function in the same function? This way there would have to create a separate function. Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

You can return both adding them into a array like

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $this->db->select(dbColumnProductsId . ',' . dbColumnProductsName . ',' . dbColumnProductsImage . ',' . dbColumnProductsPrice . ',' . dbColumnProductsStock . ',' . dbColumnCategoryId . ',' . dbColumnCategoryName);
    $this->db->join(dbTableCategory, dbTableCategory . '.' . dbColumnCategoryId . '=' . dbTableProducts . '.' . dbColumnProductsCategory);
    $this->db->order_by(dbColumnProductsId, 'DESC');
    $this->db->from(dbTableProducts);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $retun_array = array();
    $retun_array['rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    if($retun_array['rows'] > 0)
    {
         $retun_array['data']= $query->result_array();
    }

    return $retun_array;
}
```

And you can use this in you controller after getting model return for example if you store return data in $retun_array then

```
$rows = $retun_array['rows'];
if($rows > 0){
    $data = $retun_array['data']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To paging must through three stages to handle:

- Count products, you can use **$db->count_all_results();** function
- Find the limit and start
- Select products by limit and start

**dont use num_rows because its too slow**